# Bash: Capture newline with `read`

Tags: bash

I have a loop that I want to break on **any** user input.

Contrived example – a timer that counts down from 10:

```
counter=10
while (( counter > 0 )) && [[ -z $input ]]; do
    printf '\rRestart in %s seconds' "$counter"
    read -n 1 -t 1 input
    (( counter-- ))
done
echo "Completed"
```

This works appropriately for all user input **except for `Enter`**, and I fully expect that `Enter` will be the most common input.

How can I capture `Enter` using Bash's `read` command?

Comment: Fixed the syntax -- the given sample code didn't actually work -- and also made it follow some conventions.

Comment: I missed something major in my first-pass formatting/convention fix -- one shouldn't use parameter expansion in the first argument to printf (as it can lead to invalid format strings) absent extenuating circumstances. Patched that up in a subsequent pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell read to use NUL as its delimiter:

```
IFS='' read -r -d '' -n 1 -t 1 input
```

So, in full context:

```
counter=10; input=''
while (( counter > 0 )) && [[ -z $input ]]; do
    printf "\rRestart in %s seconds" "$counter"
    IFS='' read -n 1 -t 1 -d '' input
    (( counter-- ))
done
```

Answer (score 4):

The bash manual says that `read` returns success (return code zero) unless it times out.  So how about this:

```
for (( counter=10 ; counter > 0 ; counter-- )); do
    printf "\rRestart in %s seconds " $counter
    read -n 1 -t 1 input && break
done
echo "Completed"
```

Comment: +1 -- It's a cleaner solution to the OP's real problem than the one I provided. On the other hand, it doesn't actually demonstrate how to capture a newline with read, which is the question someone else who clicks on a search result for this is likely to want answered, so I'm inclined to call the accepted-answer flag rightly awarded. :)

Comment: ...a few minor quibbles, on second look -- `counter` vs `COUNTER`, and this retains the bad practice in the prior code of performing string substitution in a format string.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Here's the (ugly) finished script if you care for more context. Again, thanks! https://github.com/holyjaw/Restart-Loop/blob/master/Restart%20Loop.sh

Comment: Woops: https://github.com/holyjaw/Restart-Loop/blob/master/Restart%20Loop.command

Comment: ... and `printf` corrected too.  I'm learning some bash here myself.

Comment: One further quibble -- in this specific case, where `counter` can't contain anything but a number, it's safe to have it unquoted (as `$counter` rather than `"$counter"`) -- but in the general case it's not. If a variable contained `"foo bar"` and you used its expansion unquoted as an argument to printf, it would cause printf to emit its format string *twice* -- once with `foo` substituted, and a second time with `bar` -- rather than using the single string `foo bar`.

Comment: ...anyhow, using an unquoted expansion actually forces the shell to do more work, as it needs to check whether the value can be glob-expanded or string-split. It's actually (marginally) more efficient to quote, even when you don't need to do so for correctness.

Comment: @JoshWhittington A note on that script -- the `function` keyword actually isn't needed to define a function; the POSIX syntax to do so is just `funcname() { ... }`. Using `function funcname` confers no benefit, but adds only a point of needless incompatibility.